# How to write a good paper review?

Tags: research-process, masters, writing, peer-review

I just started my Masters in computer science, and I started working on a research project with one of my professors last term as a part of a class project for his class. In relation to that project, he has asked me to help him review a paper that is being reviewed to determine whether it will be accepted or rejected for a conference. I have agreed to review the paper. However, I have never written this type of paper review before. What are the steps you go through in reviewing a paper to determine if it should be accepted or rejected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I be a good reviewer?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42138/how-can-i-be-a-good-reviewer), also [Scope for the role of peer reviewer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/498/scope-for-the-role-of-peer-reviewer)