# Academic Journal Article Peer-Review Feedback Tips

Tags: peer-review, writing

I've always been dissapointed in the feedback I receive when submitting articles for publication. Even when my work is accepted the suggest given are often vague and unclear.

I know that most journals have some sort of form that reviewers complete but it seems that the form is not followed very carefully.

Therefore,  I was wondering what kinds of expectations others have in regards to peer-review feedback for an academic article.

Comment: To be honest, reviews from high quality journals were always helpful in my case. How many journals did you try? Do you always submit to the same journals? One more thing, in my field, we don't follow any "form" for reviewing articles. Every reviewer has his/her own style (most of the time). Low impact journals tend toward have a standard form (again in n my field).

Comment: @Fire guy I'm just beginning my career so I have about 12 articles published. I started with the lowest of the low because I actually want to have some success  getting into something. I have been working my way up into stronger journals as I have improved in my writing. So my experience is mostly with weaker journals.

Comment: I understand. My advise is to aim high, submit to higher quality journals first. Then, upon you get your review, you re-evaluate and adjust. The main benefit is, you will get mush better reviews (which will hep you tremendously [in your writing, thinking.. etc.). If you start with lower journals, you are most likely to get frustrated (hence your question here!).

Comment: This is a very broad and vague question, that IMO risks simply asking for opinions. You could probably reword it to be a better question, but there's a good chance that it would end up as a duplicate of https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42138/how-can-i-be-a-good-reviewer

Comment: Incidentally, what field are you in?  In mathematics, I've never heard of a form that reviewers complete, except in accounts of predatory journals.  Maybe this differs between fields (or my experience might not be representative of all of mathematics), but it suggests to me that you might be publishing in unusual, and possibly predatory, journals.

Comment: @anonymous I;m in education

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: I've sometimes filled out forms as a reviewer for some (perfectly respectable) journals in applied mathematics.  In some cases the questions are a rather poor fit for mathematics of any kind, and appear to have been copied over (maybe with slight modification) from journals in experimental science or some other more empirically-oriented field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Submit your work to high-quality journals.  Those journals (usually) make sure to get high-quality reviews for submitted papers.  In my own experience, the quality of the reviews is strongly correlated with the quality of the journal.